# How to sculpt with odd linear artefacts

Tags: blender, 3d-modelling

I am currently learning how to sculpt in Blender; working on my own projects after completing BlenderGuru's Beginner & Intermediate classes, and some of Grant Abbitts videos with pleasing results. I am trying to sculpt a plasmapistol with a skull on it, which can be seen in the reference photo that I have provided.

However, when I sculpt, I get these really odd linear artefacts (See picture below, circled in black). I added a Subsurf Modifier to the primitive UV Sphere, with the Viewport and Render Values set to 4, so it is a fairly fine mesh. However, these still artefacts occur.

I assume it is due to the stretching of the polygons when I grab the sphere with the Snake Hook tool and deform it to encompass the frontal part of the skull.

EDIT: Whilst writing this comment I went back, and switched on Dynamic Topology with Relative Detail selected.

It appears that I am no longer getting the issues that I was getting last night with the linear artefacts.

Can I confirm that these problems are a result of having the incorrect Dynamic Topology settings for using the Snake Hook Tool; I was using Constant Detail instead of Relative Detail, or is this being caused by another issue?

Also, any advice on avoiding common pitfalls when choosing the settings in sculpting would be most appreciated.

I will continue to ask this question incase anyone has a similar problem and it can be resolved by reading this.

[Sculpt, showing lineations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zV1v.jpg)

[Experimenting with Dynamic Topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIGFl.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In Object Mode, does the object have uniform X, Y, & Z scaling? If not, you can apply the scale from the object menu.

Object ‣ Apply ‣ Scale / Rotation & Scale